# Client-Server chat program

Tags: java, networking, server, client

I'm trying to create a Client-Server chat program in java. I want the clients to contact each other through the server at the same time. I would like to know how many threads I will be using in both the server and the client.

Comment: Minimum Threads: In the `Server Side` One main Thread in which the Server is running,one Thread for each client that is connecting.In the `Client Side`,one Thread that is waiting messages from the Server,`One Main Thread from the Applcation`.That's just a model you can use...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your design. If you design your project as all the clients would keep the connection until user quits, then you must assign a new thread for all new connections. Because, in the case keeping connection, server could do nothing except listening the connection if you try to use one thread for all connections.

However, if your clients connect to server periodically, then you can use one thread or fixed number of threads (eg: thread pool) to handle the connections.

I recommend to use thread-per-connection model to keep all the connections alive.